# How to query all data with mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My website is developed as Node.js, Express.js, and MySQL.
Recently, I have been working on converting MySQL DB to MongoDB, and there is a problem connecting MongoDB data.

I am using Mongoose, MongoDB ODM, and I read Mongoose's document and wrote the same code, but I cannot get the data.
Maybe there is a problem with schema setting or DB connection process, so I wonder how to solve it.

The data structure in my DB consists of the following.
[image: MongoDB Compass]

**[index.js]**

```
const db = require("../lib/db");
let User = require('../lib/models/userModel');
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(`HOME ROUTE!`);
  User.find(),  // Find All data in user collection
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log(result);
    }
});
```

**[userModel.js]**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)

const userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  login: String,
  id: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true
  }
});
console.log('Module Success')

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

**[db.js]**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
  console.log('DB Connected');
});

module.exports = db;
```

**[Log when connecting to Home route]**
[image]

As you can see, there are no results printed on the console, but there are no error phrases, so I don't know where the problem occurs.

Comment: User.find() => User.find({})

Comment: @AndrewShmig I tried to modify the code but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are calling **User.find** is not correct, Check below, updated working index.js

```
const db = require("../lib/db");
let User = require('../lib/models/userModel');
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(`HOME ROUTE!`);
  User.find({}, function (err, result) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log(result);
    })
});
```